# AWS SAM Nested Application in Python with Dynamorm

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I am using [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) to build a Serverless application. I followed the instruction to build [a nested application](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-nested-applications-for-aws-sam-and-the-aws-serverless-application-repository/).

My application structure is basically the following:

```
.
├── MAKEFILE
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── apps
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── account
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── endpoints.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── requirements.txt
│   │   └── template.yaml
├── samconfig.toml
└── template.yaml
```

The `requirements.txt` in the folder `apps/account/` has the following python packages: `boto3` `marshmallow` and `dynamorm`.

The `sam build` and `sam deploy` works fine and the lambda functions are deployed correctly. However, I receive an error when calling the lambda function. The logs show the following error `Unable to import module 'endpoints': No module named 'dynamorm'`.

Here are excerpts from my code:

**endpoints.py**

```
import json
import boto3

from models import Account

print('Loading function')

def account_info(event, context):

    apiKey = event["requestContext"]["identity"]["apiKeyId"]

    account_info = Account.get(id= apiKey)

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(account_info)
    }
```

**models.py**

```
import datetime

from dynamorm import DynaModel, GlobalIndex, ProjectAll

from marshmallow import Schema, fields, validate, validates, ValidationError

class Account(DynaModel):
    # Define our DynamoDB properties
    class Table:
        name = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
        hash_key = 'id'
        read = 10
        write = 5

    class Schema:
        id = fields.String(required=True)
        name = fields.String()
        email = fields.String()
        phonenumber = fields.String()
        status = fields.String()
```

I am not sure what am I missing? Are there additional instructions to build a nested app in SAM?

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/1213, this feature is not supported yet.

In my case, I did 'sam build' on every nested stacks and fix parent yaml template as following (use template.yaml generated by sam build command), then works. But just workaround and not nice way.

```
  XXX_APP:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Application
    Properties:
      Location: nest_application/.aws-sam/build/template.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks Benny. It worked. However, I agree this should be supported.