# Deploying AWS SAM application does not deploy depedencies for Lambda

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I have two SAM applications, both of which have a set of Python Lambdas in common. I have a different template file for each application.

When I run `sam deploy` for the first one it correctly deploys the Lambdas with their dependencies. For the second it only deploys the application code.

I can see all the dependencies correctly there in the `.aws-sam/build` directory.

Using `--debug` doesn't give me any useful information.

How do I go about debugging this?

Should the zip files that it deploys be available somewhere on my local system, and if so where?

Comment: Hi Nick, can you share your template file.

Comment: Is the 2nd nested application? If yes, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141845/aws-sam-nested-application-in-python-with-dynamorm/60180099#60180099

Comment: Sorry I haven't been back to this. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/1252#issuecomment-621667137 covers some of the issues.

I need to spend some time to work out the correct solution, but basically sam doesn't work with multiple template files in the same directory